# Canonical term for $\overline X / X$ where $X$ is a normed space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, terminology

Let $X$ be a normed vector space.

Let $\overline X$ denote its completion.

Is there a canonical name for the quotient space $\overline X / X$?

Some authors seem to use "torsion" as a name, but I cannot relate that to any known torsion concept.

Comment: Does one consider that quotient for any other purpose than the dimension? An indiscrete topological vector space is not particularly interesting in general, or is it?

Comment: This appears in the theory of Hilbert complexes, as quotient of the closure of the boundaries by the boundaries.
More, generally, for Banach complexes see: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02922133?LI=true